# PhoneGap database working on emulator, but not on device

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

Im just learning PhoneGap and I have some problems conserning the databases...

SO I want to connect to my localhost databse and simply display the items from the table.. With the ripple emulator everything works, but when I install the app on my device the data is not displayed, but im not getting any errors either.

So I am using the PhoneGap Desktop App. The server is running on `http://88.216.170.246:3000`

So in my ajax I do this:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.show', function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url:"http://88.216.170.246/Test/www/getData.php",
                    success: function(result) {
                        if (result) {
                            $(".show_data").html(result);
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    }
                    });
                });
            });
```

This renders everything perfectly on the emulator, but on my phone, nothing happens... Does the url not work? Maybe I cant access localhost on my device?

Comment: It maybe because of access origing issue --- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS  --. Try putting this line at the top of your  PHP script -- (header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); )   -- if you think you cant access anything from the url, open the mobiles browsers and put (http://88.216.170.246/) do you see anything or do you get an error

Comment: For some reason I cant access the localhost in my browser at all... Why is that?

Comment: without knowing what kind of web server setup you have i cant tell

Answer (score 0):

Please read:

*Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap*
https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md
READ #1, #4, #5, & #10

#### #4 reads

**In the code, did not listen for the 'deviceready' event.**

This is listed MULTIPLE times in the documentation, and is include in every example where it is appropriate. It is still missed. Brian Ford - an Angular developer, points to the section of documentation we need.

> This is a very important event that every Cordova application should use.
>
> Cordova consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the native code is loading, a custom loading image is displayed. However, JavaScript is only loaded once the DOM loads. This means your web application could, potentially, call a Cordova JavaScript function before it is loaded.
>
> The Cordova deviceready event fires once Cordova has fully loaded. After the device has fired, you can safely make calls to Cordova function.

Please read the FAQ and follow the links. You have made many bad assumptions.

Best of Luck
Jesse